# component next/image are not working with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, nextjs-image

I was trying to make border around an image and my custom css was not working because of Image component css, it was overriding over my custom css and also applied tailwind and bootstrap to fix it but I was unable to fix it. Now I am not getting any clue to fix it I read some github issues but they are not enough to fix it.

**code**:[code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/imgstyling-ttz1m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how to use `:global(_selectors_here_)` with `!important`:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import sli from "./sl.png";
export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image className="ava" src={sli} alt="hello" />
      <style jsx>{`
        :global(.ava) {
          border: 3px solid red !important;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This did work for me.

Thanks a bunch.

Any thoughts on why this works...

Answer (score 0):

To make className work in external component, you have to either use [:global](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#global-styles) or [the resolve tag](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#the-resolve-tag).

And to override inline styles, with tailwindcss, you can use [important modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#built-in-important-modifier) like `!border`.